# Plugin doesnt respond to action :hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of code for my plugin like this:

```
var element = $("*[data-label]");
(function ($) {
    $.fn.Label = function (options) {
        var label = $(this).attr("data-label"),
            d = document.createElement('span'),
            t = document.createTextNode(label),
            config = $.extend({
            display: 'inline',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '6.5em',
            padding: '0.5em',
            backgroundColor: '#383838',
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '0.8em',
            opacity: '0.9',
        }, options);
        if (element.is(":hover")) {
            d.className = "labelShow";
            $(this).append(d);
            $('.labelShow').append(t).css(config);
        } else {
            $(".labelShow").remove();
            return false;
        }
    };

}(jQuery));

element.Label();
```

I have no errors in console, and debugger dont catch any events when I'm hovering element I'd like to respond to my widget code. Could you give me any hints why it doesn't work?

Comment: Advice use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) `var label = $(this).data("label"),`

Comment: I changed it but this still doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure your element is being captured?

Comment: You should try this to begin with -> `var element = $("*[data-label]"); element.css("background-color", "#ff0");`

Comment: @Nephie it will not make your code work.It's just for improving your code.

Comment: Yes, element is captured well because this is copyied from my code which worked but was written bad. And your code works of course, so element is fine.

Comment: That will show if the elements are actually being captured or not, and give us some feedback to help us determine the problem

Comment: Tushar, you're right :D Thanks for advice anyway ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.Label = function (options) {
        //create a shared css def for the label
        var css = $.extend({
            display: 'inline',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '6.5em',
            padding: '0.5em',
            backgroundColor: '#383838',
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: '0.8em',
            opacity: '0.9'
        }, options);

        //append the label span to each element in the jquery element set on which the plugin was initialized
        this.append(function () {
            return $('<span />', {
                text: $(this).data('label'),
                'class': 'labelShow'
            }).css(css).hide();
        //register mouser enter and mouse leave events for each of the elements so that the label can be displayed or hidden
        }).hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.labelShow').show();
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('.labelShow').hide();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

var element = $("*[data-label]");
element.Label();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xbSKk/)